W/FlutterJNI(21251): Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send
I'm trying to make an Android real-time object detection app with a custom model. I've added my model, but I get this problem when running the code. I'm new to Flutter, so I couldn't solve the problem...

W/FlutterJNI(21251): Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but
FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel:
plugins.flutter.io/camera_android/imageStream. Response ID: 783

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  camera: ^0.10.6
  get: ^4.6.6
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1
  flutter_tflite: ^1.0.1
  image: ^3.2.0

build.gradle
android {
    namespace "com.example.beet"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'tflite'
        noCompress 'lite'
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
       (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.beet"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

Scan Controller
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tflite/flutter_tflite.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;


class ScanController extends GetxController {
  late CameraController cameraController;
  late List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  var isCameraInitialized = false.obs;

  var cameraCount = 0;
  var x = 0.0, y = 0.0, w = 0.0, h = 0.0;
  var label = "";

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    initCamera();
    initTFLite();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> initCamera() async {
    if (await Permission.camera.request().isGranted) {
      cameras = await availableCameras();
      cameraController = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.max);

      try {
        await cameraController.initialize().then((_) {
          isCameraInitialized(true);
          cameraController.startImageStream((image) {
            cameraCount++;
            if (cameraCount % 10 == 0) {
              cameraCount = 0;
              objectDetector(image);
            }
          });
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print("Camera initialization error: $e");
      }
    } else {
      print("Camera permission denied");
    }
    update();
  }

  Future<void> initTFLite() async {
    try {
      await Tflite.loadModel(
        model: "assets/best.tflite",
        labels: "assets/label.txt",
        isAsset: true,
        numThreads: 1,
        useGpuDelegate: false,
      );
      print("Model loaded successfully");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error loading model: $e");
    }
  }

  Uint8List imageToByteListFloat32(img.Image image, int inputSize) {
    var convertedBytes = Float32List(1 * inputSize * inputSize * 3);
    var buffer = Float32List.view(convertedBytes.buffer);
    int pixelIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < inputSize; j++) {
        var pixel = image.getPixel(j, i);
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getRed(pixel) / 127.5) - 1;
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getGreen(pixel) / 127.5) - 1;
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getBlue(pixel) / 127.5) - 1;
      }
    }
    return convertedBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  Future<void> objectDetector(CameraImage image) async {
    print("Starting object detection");
    final int width = image.width;
    final int height = image.height;

    // Convert CameraImage to Image package format
    img.Image imgImage = img.Image(width, height);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        final int uvIndex = (i ~/ 2) * (image.planes[1].bytesPerRow ~/ 2) + (j ~/ 2);
        final int index = i * width + j;
        final y = image.planes[0].bytes[index];
        final u = image.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];
        final v = image.planes[2].bytes[uvIndex];
        imgImage.setPixel(j, i, yuvToRgb(y, u, v));
      }
    }

    // Resize the image to the size your model expects
    img.Image resizedImage = img.copyResize(imgImage, width: 224, height: 224);
    Uint8List input = imageToByteListFloat32(resizedImage, 224);

    var detector = await Tflite.runModelOnFrame(
      bytesList: [input],
      imageHeight: 224,
      imageWidth: 224,
      imageMean: 0.0,
      imageStd: 1.0,
      numResults: 1,
      rotation: 90,
      threshold: 0.4,
    );

    if (detector != null && detector.isNotEmpty) {
      print("Object detected: $detector");
      var ourDetectedObject = detector.first;
      if (ourDetectedObject['confidenceInClass'] * 100 > 45) {
        label = ourDetectedObject['detectedClass'].toString();
        h = ourDetectedObject['rect']['h'];
        w = ourDetectedObject['rect']['w'];
        x = ourDetectedObject['rect']['x'];
        y = ourDetectedObject['rect']['y'];
      } else {
        print("Detection confidence too low");
      }
    } else {
      print("No objects detected");
    }
    update();
  }

  int yuvToRgb(int y, int u, int v) {
    int r = (y + (1.370705 * (v - 128))).toInt();
    int g = (y - (0.337633 * (u - 128)) - (0.698001 * (v - 128))).toInt();
    int b = (y + (1.732446 * (u - 128))).toInt();
    r = r.clamp(0, 255);
    g = g.clamp(0, 255);
    b = b.clamp(0, 255);
    return img.getColor(r, g, b);
  }
}


Camera view
import 'package:beet1/controller/scan_controller.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class CameraView extends StatelessWidget {
  const CameraView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GetBuilder<ScanController>(
        init: ScanController(),
        builder: (controller) {
          if (!controller.isCameraInitialized.value) {
            return const Center(child: Text("Loading Preview"));
          }

          return Stack(
            children: [
              CameraPreview(controller.cameraController),
              Positioned(
                top: (controller.y * context.height).toDouble(),
                right: (controller.x * context.width).toDouble(),
                child: Container(
                  width: (controller.w * context.width).toDouble(),
                  height: (controller.h * context.height).toDouble(),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 4.0),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Text(controller.label),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


I've googled the problem but couldn't quite understand what to do. I have checked the following:

https://medium.com/@gauravpaudel2013/tried-to-send-a-platform-message-to-flutter-but-flutterjni-was-detached-from-native-c-well-well-c7d9ccf0df96
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117061.


in which line do you get this error message?

It's not exactly in a line. When I run the code the program works without an error but can't detect any object. When I stop the code I get this error.

What do you mean by when you stop the code? Have you tried to use an existing image instead of the camera to narrow down where root of the problem is?
